# python: replace words in file with words from other file

Tags: python, csv, str-replace

I have a large text-file in which there are words I want to replace. I put those words in a csv-file, because I'm constantly adding and changing words and do not want to put the words in the python script itself. On each line is a word I want to replace, followed by the word I want to replace it with. Like this:

```
A_old,A_new
another word,another new word
something old,something new
hello,bye
```

I know how to replace single words in files with python with the string replace function, but I don't know how to do this when the words are listed in a different file. I tried my best, but I can't wrap my head around how to work with dictionaries/lists/tuples. I am rather new to python, and until now I managed with examples from around the internet, but this is beyond my capabilities. I got all kinds of errors like 'unhashable type: list' and 'expected a character buffer object'. 
The last thing I tried was the most succesful in that I didn't get any errors, but then nothing happened either. This is the code. I'm sure it's ugly, but I hope it's not entirely hopeless.

```
reader = csv.reader(open('words.csv', 'r'))
d = {}
for row in reader:
    key, value = row
    d[key] = value

newwords = str(d.keys())
oldwords = str(d.values())

with open('new.txt', 'wt') as outfile:
    with open('old.txt', 'rt') as infile:
        for line in infile:
            outfile.write(line.replace(oldwords,newwords))
```

The reason I am doing this is because I'm working on a cookbook with an ingredient based index, and I don't want an index with both 'carrot' and 'carrots', instead I want to change 'carrot' into 'carrots', and so on for all the other ingredients. 
Thanks a bunch for a nudge in the right direction!

Comment: For one thing, you need to use `d[key] = [value]` in order to create a dict of lists, rather than `d[key] = value`.

Comment: But it's not clear why you have a dict of lists at all; that's not the correct data model here. A plain dict of strings will do.

Comment: Regular `replace` might not be suitable for this task. Suppose you do get the dict stuff sorted out, and you finally replace all instances of "carrot" in your file with "carrots". But this will also replace all existing instances of "carrots" with "carrotss". `replace` doesn't only look for full words to replace; it will happily replace parts of words.

Comment: Thanks so far. @Kevin, this won't be a problem. It's an index made with LaTex, in which every entry is separated by an exclamation mark, so I'll search for "!carrot!" and replace it with "!carrots!". Tom I made an adjustment to the first part of the code. Not sure if that's what you meant. If not, I will go and Google some more on this dict stuff..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you make a list of pairs (old_word, new_word) from 'word.csv' :

```
old_new = [i.strip().split(',') for i in open('words.csv')]
```

Then, you can replace line by line :

```
with open('new.txt', 'w') as outfile, open('old.txt') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        for oldword, newword in old_new:
            line = line.replace(oldword, newword)
        outfile.write(line)
```

or in the whole file at once :

```
with open('new.txt', 'w') as outfile, open('old.txt') as infile:
    txt = infile.read()
    for oldword, newword in old_new:
        txt = txt.replace(oldword, newword)    
    outfile.write(txt)
```

but you have to replace one word at a time.

Comment: This seems to work like a charm! Both line by line as the whole file at once. Don't have enough reputation yet to up-vote your answer though. I'm so relieved. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In your code example you read the replacement word pairs into a dictionary, and then into two lists with keys and values. I'm not sure why.

I propose to read the replacement words into a list of tuples.

```
with open('words.csv', 'rb') as rep_words:
    rep_list = []
    for rep_line in rep_words:
        rep_list.append(tuple(rep_line.strip().split(',')))
```

Then you can open the `old.txt` and `new.txt` files and perform the replacement using a nested for loop

```
with open('old.txt', 'rb') as old_text:
    with open('new.txt', 'wb') as new_text:
        for read_line in old_text:
            new_line = read_line
            for old_word, new in rep_list:
                new_line = new_line.replace(old_word, new_word))
            new_text.write(new_line)
```

Comment: I tried this, but only the last pair of words from the csv-file were replaced in the text files. Don't know where it went wrong. Thanks for thinking along anyway!

Comment: by the way, I'm not sure why I made a dictionary and then two lists either :) Thanks for mentioning the tuples, I'll make sure to read some more on this subject.